# UCP PoolDataSourceImpl with ConnectionInitializationCallback

Tags: java, oracle, pooling, ucp

I am attempting to configure a UCP PoolDataSourceImpl with a ConnectionInitializationCallback.  Here's my configuration:

```
private static DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties) throws SQLException, UniversalConnectionPoolException {
    UniversalConnectionPoolManager ucpm        = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();
    PoolDataSource                 pds         = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    final String                   editionName = properties.getProperty("jdbc.editionName", "ora$base");

    pds.registerConnectionInitializationCallback(new oracle.ucp.jdbc.ConnectionInitializationCallback() {
        public void initialize(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            LOG.debug("Attempting to set edition to: {}", editionName);
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.executeUpdate("ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = " + editionName);
            }
            LOG.debug("Edition set to: {}", editionName);
        }
    });

    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    pds.setUser(properties.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    pds.setPassword(properties.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    pds.setURL(properties.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    pds.setConnectionPoolName("demo-pool");
    pds.setInitialPoolSize(3);
    pds.setMaxPoolSize(3);
    pds.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);

    LOG.debug("Created DataSource Pool");
    ucpm.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter)pds);
    ucpm.startConnectionPool("demo-pool");

    return pds;
}
```

However the initialize method is never called.  I'm using java 1.7.0_51 with the following Oracle jars:

ojdbc6.jar - v12.1.0.1.0
ucp.jar - v12.1.0.0.0

I have managed to make this work by removing the call to "registerConnectionInitializationCallback" and replacing it with a call to "registerConnectionLabelingCallback" but from my understanding this will exeute the ALTER SESSION each time a connection is requested from the pool rather then when it is actually created.

Any help with getting the ConnectionInitializationCallback to work would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

The ConnectionInitializationCallback mechanism appears to be a part of the "[Application Continuity](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/appcontnew.htm#JJDBC29059)" feature released with 12c. Application Continuity requires that you use one of the following DataSource implementations:

- oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl
- oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleConnectionPoolDataSourceImpl

I haven't tried it for myself, but I'm guessing if you use one of these DataSource implementations, your ConnectionInitializationCallback will work.

It would've been nice if this had been included as part of the standard UCP implementation, much like Connection Labeling.